# Does the speed of a knight jousting increase their impact taken and dealt?

Tags: forces, speed

For example, lets say you have 2 knights jousting, and their horses are just walking slowly. I would assume that when each knight's lance hits the other, they wouldn't really get pushed much at all. But if their horses were galloping at fast speeds, then they would both take heavy impact. Its like a car hitting a wall at 2 km/h versus one at 100km/h.

How would the "strength" of knights jousting be affected by speed in these scenarios, and what is the probable event (i.e, do they get knocked a little, or do they fall off their horse):

A) Both knights' horses walking very slowly
B) Both knights' horses galloping very fast
C) One knight is walking/stationary, and the other is galloping very fast

Also an abstract question: would a faster knight hit more harder, and will also get hit more harder too?

Comment: what physics principle do you think is involved here?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I don't really know much about physics, but I'm guessing something to do with mass and acceleration. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of the two knights' speed will have a great impact in terms of power, damage dealt and taken. power can be gathered by getting the product of force and velocity. so since the force and velocity are directly proportional to power (power=velocity*time) but not to each other (force=power/velocity or force=1/velocity) and (velocity=1/force) therefore, if the situation is that both of the knights have the same force but knight-b is much faster (which means that he has a longer displacement and less time) than knight-a the power will struck knight-a will take much more damage. the only thing that knight-b will be disadvantaged is in terms of the energy that will return in the hand to the whole body since he has a higher power.

Comment: I don't really understand this. Assuming both knights are equipped the same (same armour, same lance), if B is faster than A, then A will get hit harder? Also I don't know the difference between power and force

Comment: yes, power is the product of velocity and force which means that "force" and "velocity" is a factor of power. if broken down
Force = mass*acceleration 
Velocity = Distance/time

Comment: there are fundamental quantities and derived quantities, fundamental quantities are basic quantities that can be measured using a device (mass, time, temperature etc). acceleration is a derived quantity distance is a fundamental quantity which is length, ACCELERATION is the ability to gain speed in a short period of time, MASS is the property of a matter to have inertia(to remain unchanged) time is time.

Comment: REMEMBER:  POWER=(Mass x Acceleration) x (distance/time)
                                                              Force                                 Velocity

so if force or velocity is doubled the answer will also be doubled, since they are directly proportional to each other. however this is only effective to their general form. if time is doubled then the power will be lesser, because it is inversely proportional to power.

Comment: So I'm confirming that to calculate "power", you will need 4 variables (distance, time, mass, acceleration) right? Also I'm no expert here (obviously), but how does one object, out of 2 that are to collide with each other, take more of an impact? Logically I believe there is no difference in "result" in me running my head towards a wall, or me standing still and getting whacked by a moving wall (assuming the speeds were the same)

Comment: Also, given that B is faster than A, wouldn't that mean that B would not only deal more impact to A, but would also take more impact as well? Like walking towards a wall wouldn't hurt your head as much as sprinting towards a wall?

Comment: yes. in your second question the when two objects perform each others actions (in your case the wall and you) if you say that both objects have the same speed they will not differ however there is a difference in mass which is a crucial factor in the said variable "power". To put it in simple terms in a highway CAR-A is going north, CAR-B is going south on the same road (assuming that there are no factors involved other than the car and flat road) CAR-A broke down and stopped while the blind driver of CAR-B is crashed into CAR-A.

Comment: CAR-A will fly backwards to his position since........... yes his INERTIA or THE ABILITY TO RESIST MOTION has been destroyed by the impact and transfer of energy fro car b. this time VELOCITY is the main cause of change (this is you sprinting towards your twin). A truck and an SUV will have another result.

Comment: to your third question, try punching a wall (remember you are the one punching the wall, the wall is but a stationary object) when you punch the wall and an impact will occur the transfer of energy will MAINLY go to the wall but then back to your hand, that is why you feel pain. you have seen a rubber band right if you fling a rubber band it will bend back and fort right, that is how 2 objects react to each other when in contact. we just don't see it. if you cant imagine it, make your hands in inverted form like this )( then clap.

Comment: can you feel the vibration? that is how two objects react to each other . now try holding your left hand up and slapping it using your right hand. it is more painful in the left correct however you can still pain in your right hand. that is the energy transfer that I am talking about.  have you heard your teachers say if someone punches don't punch them back because you have already dealt some damage to them, specifically the hand that they used to punch. yes that is also the transfer of energy.

Comment: Given your car example, what would be the power or "damage" given and taken for each car? (e.g: Car A sustains x damage and deals y damage, Car B sustains z damage and deals aa damage). And I'm assuming that in say, some scenario x: sedan crashes into stationary suv won't push the suv as far, compared to a stationary sedan.

Comment: I'm sorry I cant solve that right now i'm busy with work, but in the sedan and suv question. if the SUV is twice the weight of the sedan, the SUV will not be pushed as far as when the situation is turned. now Mass is the factor that will change the result. now, the energy transfer is like a ricochet once you hit an object in a fast pace the object will return but not as far and strong as it's first movement. the reason why I cant answer is because there are many factors that are to be calculated.

Comment: Thats ok. This may be off topic, but I'm willing to pay for your time to get more insight on this, for later. Is there any way to contact you perhaps?

Comment: I'm really sorry as an engineer I don't have the luxury to spend time in my own will but you can chat to physics group chats which will help you, I'm willing to help for free as long as I got the time but then again work calls.